# Controlling number of AppWidget instance

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I want to create a widget for my android app that display some real time details about locations e.g. weather. but i want to **allow max 3 instances of the widget** at any point of time, each with a different location. I am not sure how to go about it and can't find any information.

my questions are:

1. Is there a limit on number of appWidget instances that could be created?
2. How to go about limiting the number of widget instances user can create at any point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are multiple ways to count the app widgets that i can think of:

1. send an intent to all of your app widgets to see that they still exist, and count them, and only in the end you would know how many there are. however, i'm not sure how you would know when to stop counting.
2. not sure if it works but maybe you could use:

   > ```
   > final ComponentName cn=new ComponentName(context,YourAppWidgetProviderClass.class);
   > int[] appWidgetsIds=appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(cn);
   > ```

   and check the size of the result.
3. update the counter based on receving the ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED (or ACTION_APPWIDGET_DISABLED) and  ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND (or ACTION_APPWIDGET_ENABLED) actions in the intents on the onReceive() method of your AppWidgetProvider class.

anyway, if there are too many (4 or more in your case) , just show an alternative layout for the new widget.

you would also need to handle the case of removing app widgets (those that weren't disabled) so that you would enable new ones (and decrease the counter), or you could let the user click on disabled ones to trigger the check again.

about limiting the creation itself, i don't think it's possible, but as i wrote, it's possible to count them and disable new ones.

do note that the user might have the app widget available on more than one app . it doesn't even have to be a launcher that will show your app widget. also not sure how it would work in case there are multiple users (available on android 4.2 and above) .

Comment: counted the appWidgetIds in the onUpdate(), the second method you mentioned. just had to add one line and hey presto. That's where i wanted the count really. 
I am also using alternative layout as the count increases.
Still trying to figure out a clean way to limit number of widget instances. Will update if i get it.
Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: please try out as many tests and end cases on the method you've chosen. i've never done such a thing so i'm not sure about the consequences.

Comment: @JSmith i think that limiting is possible. you can set a configuration activity (via the xml of the appWidget) that will be called each time the user is about to create a new appWidget, and return OK in case it's ok to create a new one , and CANCEL in case it shouldn't.

Comment: @JSmith beware of the results of counting the number of appWidgetIds in the array returned by appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(cn). There's  a known bug that causes "phantom" widget instances, i.e. widgets not present on home screen but with IDs reported by AppWidgetManager as in use. I think it was solved recently, not sure in which SDK version

Comment: The second method is not reliable. I got it to work in my app and once (just one time) realized the result is _more than the real number of the widgets_. Also, I suspect to the third method. I think it is possible that one (or more) widget(s) removed in real, but `ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED` not fired for some reasons (in some complex situations). So you count the widgets more than their actual number. But I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: @Mir-Ismaili In that case, it's a bug, and you should make a sample project and report about it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Developer%20bug%20report